# Java MergeSort-printing out the two halves at each recursive step

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

For homework, I have to edit the mergeSort method so that it prints out the two halves of the array at each recursive step.

I've added a print statement using a toString() method at the recursive steps (when you sort each half), but I'm not doing it correctly, and it's printing the locations of the objects instead of the actual object that is the array.

Not sure what to do.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort extends ConsoleProgram
{
    /*
     * Do not make changes to this method!
     */
    public void run()
    {
        int[] array1 = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        int[] array2 = {5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7, 3, 1, 2};

        System.out.print("First array: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
        System.out.print("Second array: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
        System.out.println();

        // sort first array
        mergeSort(array1);
        // sort second array
        mergeSort(array2);

        System.out.print("First array sorted: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
        System.out.print("Second array sorted: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
    }

    /*
     * Merge sort takes in an array and sorts it.
     */
    public static void mergeSort(int[] arr) 
    {
        if (arr.length <= 1) 
        {
            return;
        }

        // Split the array in half
        int[] firstHalf = new int[arr.length / 2];
        int[] secondHalf = new int[arr.length - firstHalf.length];


        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, firstHalf, 0, firstHalf.length);
        System.arraycopy(arr, firstHalf.length, secondHalf, 0, secondHalf.length);


         // Sort each half
        mergeSort(firstHalf);
        mergeSort(secondHalf);

        System.out.println(firstHalf.toString());
        System.out.println(secondHalf.toString());



        // Merge the halves together
        merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, arr);


    }

    /*
     * merge takes in three arrays. The first two are the two halves of an array 
     * to be merged. The result is the resulting array that consists of the elements
     * in the two half arrays, sorted.
     */
    private static void merge(int[] firstHalf, int[] secondHalf, int [] result) 
    {

        // set up indices for iteration through arrays
        int firstIndex = 0;
        int secondIndex = 0;
        int resultIndex = 0;

        // while there are still elements in both halves, find which is smaller
        // and add it to the result array first. Then, add the larger.
        while (firstIndex < firstHalf.length && secondIndex < secondHalf.length) 
        {
            if (firstHalf[firstIndex] < secondHalf[secondIndex]) 
            {
                result[resultIndex] = firstHalf[firstIndex];
                firstIndex++;
            } 
            else 
            {
                result[resultIndex] = secondHalf[secondIndex];
                secondIndex++;
            }
            resultIndex++;

        }

        // There might be left over elements in one of the halves.
        // Copy it over as well.
        System.arraycopy(firstHalf, firstIndex, result, resultIndex, firstHalf.length - firstIndex);
        System.arraycopy(secondHalf, secondIndex, result, resultIndex, secondHalf.length - secondIndex);


    }

}
```

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString()`

Comment: Please do not use Javascript snippets for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstHalf));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondHalf));
```